# Docker. Подключение к Mysql контейнеру в Laravel

Tags: mysql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Всем привет, подскажите плиз, есть 3 контейнера собранные по отдельности через docker-compose. Nginx + Mysql + Php/Laravel. Все контейнеры запущены и находятся в одной docker сети, нужно в laravel соедниться с mysql, в .env

```
#Database settings
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=primary-mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cdn
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

primary-mysql - название контейнера который в общей сети с остальными контейнерами,

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  mysql-master:
    container_name: $PRIMARY_MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME
    image: 'mysql:$PRIMARY_MYSQL_VERSION'
    volumes:
      - '$PRIMARY_MYSQL_DATA_DIR:/var/lib/mysql'
      - '$PRIMARY_MYSQL_CONFIG_DIR/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d'
      - '$PRIMARY_MYSQL_LOGS_DIR:/var/log/mysql'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=$PRIMARY_MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=$PRIMARY_MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=$PRIMARY_MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$PRIMARY_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD=$PRIMARY_MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - '$PRIMARY_MYSQL_PUBLIC_PORT:3306'
    restart: always
    user: '1000:1000'
    cpus: '${DOCKER_LIMIT_CPUS_DB}'
    cpu_count: '${DOCKER_LIMIT_CPU_COUNT_DB}'
    mem_limit: '${DOCKER_LIMIT_MEM_DB}'
    networks:
      services_network:
        aliases:
          - $PRIMARY_MYSQL_CONTAINER_NAME
networks:
  services_network:
    external:
      name: $SERVICE_NETWORK_NAME
```

вроде все сделал правильно, но почему то получаю 500 без текста, может что то мог упустить кто нибудь знает?
Логи контейнера с php

```
172.11.0.2 -  26/фев/2022:12:14:09 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
172.11.0.2 -  26/фев/2022:12:28:01 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
172.11.0.2 -  26/фев/2022:12:28:59 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
```

Comment: почему вы решили, что причина 500 ошибки в подключении к БД? Добавьте в вопрос информацию с логами каждого контейнера ```docker logs```

Comment: Добавил логи контейнера php остальные контейнеры не отдает логов

Comment: @ilyaaa521 Смотрите логи Laravel, там точно есть информация об ошибках.